# iCalendar creation: RFC 5546 explanation

Tags: ios5, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar, lightning

I am facing several issues related to the creation of an ICS file which has to be compatible with several clients, especially `iOS`, `Gmail`, `Outlook`, `Android` and `Windows Phone`. Googling around, I found out the proposed standard from 2009, aka [RFC5546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546). I read through this document and found a point which is very interesting and could potentially solve my issue. Section [Methods for VEVENT Calendar Components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2) explains the distinctions between methods REQUEST and PUBLISH. But, there are a couple of points which are not really clear to me:

1. What should PUBLISH do? Should it add a new calendar? Should it create a new calendar (like in Outlook or iOS) or should add the event in the existing user calendar (like in Gmail or Lightning)? *EDIT: note the calendar as a file attached to an e-mail.*
2. Can PUBLISH contain more than one event? From the document and logically, yes, but Gmail then adds only the first event of the list. Lightning adds only one event and then gives a 804a0004 error.
3. How should REQUEST work? The document states: `VEVENT | 1+ | All components MUST have the same UID.` which means a calendar may have more than 1 VEVENT but they must have the same UID. Then, how can I client distinguish between those events? And in fact no client I tried is able to distinguish the events generated with the same UID, but they add only the one with highest SEQUENCE. Logically, I don't want to send more than one event per invitation, but the RFC allows me to do that (and in my case study I want to), so how?
4. With REQUEST, forgetting the statement `VEVENT | 1+ | All components MUST have the same UID.`, so providing a unique UID to each event in the ICS file, Gmail and iOS add all the events contained in the file, while Lightning and Outlook add only the first one. Is there a way to pursue this path or since it should not be allowed I should find another way?
5. Basically, how do you suggest to proceed to add more events with a single ICS file to the users' calendar for the platforms I mentioned?

Sample ICS for PUBLISH:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//prodid//product//IT
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1
DTSTAMP:20130515T121437Z
DTSTART:20130619T205000
DTEND:20130619T215000
DESCRIPTION:Desc 1
SUMMARY:Sum 1
LOCATION:location
ORGANIZER:mailto:organizer@somedomain
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid2
DTSTAMP:20130515T121437Z
DTSTART:20130719T205000
DTEND:20130719T215000
DESCRIPTION:Desc 2
SUMMARY:Sum 2
LOCATION:location
ORGANIZER:mailto:organizer@somedomain
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Sample for REQUEST:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//prodid//product//IT
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1
DTSTAMP:20130515T121437Z
DTSTART:20130619T205000
DTEND:20130619T215000
DESCRIPTION:Desc 1
SUMMARY:Sum 1
LOCATION:location
ORGANIZER:mailto:organizer@somedomain
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN=attendee cn:mailto:attendee@email
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid2
DTSTAMP:20130515T121437Z
DTSTART:20130719T205000
DTEND:20130719T215000
DESCRIPTION:Desc 2
SUMMARY:Sum 2
LOCATION:location
ORGANIZER:mailto:organizer@somedomain
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN=attendee cn:mailto:attendee@email
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

About 1) it is not clear how you communicate the events to the client: is it via iMIP (email) or through an HTTP URL ? In any case, there is no right answer to your question: iTIP is about transport of iCalendar data.

About 2) yes, you can have multiple events in a PUBLISH stream

About 3):

iCalendar has a notion of exception for recurring meetings. Those exceptions are represented by a VEVENT with the same UID and a RECURRENCE-ID indicating the particular instance that shall be considered an exception.

As a consequence, a REQUEST can only be used to transmit a single event (only one UID) but this event itself might be expressed as a set of VEVENT: one for the master (e.g. meeting every friday at 10:00) and one for each exception (e.g. except on Friday 12/12 where it will take place at 09:00).

See for example the last event in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-4.4.8

Comment: I updated the question for point 1), anyway I am sending the calendar via mail, whether as attachment or embedded in the body is not important. About point 2), does that mean that clients like Google Calendar or Lightning are kind of buggy or incomplete? Then clearly there is no way to send a single a file working for several clients, am I right?

Comment: You are right, they dont behave correctly. I would suspect that they treat PUBLISH in the same way as REQUEST, and hence allow for only one event (optionnally with VEVENT exceptions), although from 4), it looks like gmail is doing the exact opposite of what it should do.

Comment: I was wrong about 4. I finally took a more scientific approach and I am preparing a document describing the behaviour for some combinations of number of events, client, UID and method. Google calendar adds only the first event.