# icalendar two and more events together via JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, icalendar

I tried to put two events together in one ICS. To do this I helped an example put on this forum:

```
(...)
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//bobbin v0.1//NONSGML iCal Writer//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100701T080000Z
DTEND:20100701T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yoursever.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 1
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100701T120000Z
DTEND:20100701T130000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003b@yoursever.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 2
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
(...)
```

The result was that the invitation noticed inside the calendar only first event, the second was omitted.

What was wrong?

I observed the same result in Outlook and Gmail.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567269/icalendar-creation-rfc-5546-explanation/16592486#16592486

Answer (score 0):

if you want to import many events :

To gmail , you could implement the api of gmail calendar ,

To outlook , you can alter the icalendar method to "publish" , and it would create new calendar , the new calendar will include many events

if you send just an appointment ,   that would not be a problem , but if you have many appointments, it  would be a problem , because its  weird if you include many events in an email or you send per appointment per mail